# Print the minimum length of Validator for Reactive Form

Tags: angular

How can I get the min length value in the form?

```
<div *ngIf="dataForm.get('description').hasError('minlength') && dataForm.get('description').touched">
   The product description minimum length is {{ dataForm.controls.description.minlength }}.
</div>
```

I tried `dataForm.controls.description.minlength` and it prints nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataForm.get('description').getError('minlength').requiredLength`

Shameless plug: I would strongly advise avoiding to hardcode and repeat all these checks in your forms and use [ngx-valdemort](https://ngx-valdemort.ninja-squad.com/) instead.